# I want to reset/reload a JFrame so all fields are set back to default value

Tags: java, swing, jframe, reload, reset

I have several different text fields, combo boxes etc. I want to reset them all back to their defaults (as if the program was just opened) without doing it manually.. i.e. `xField.text = ""`, or whatever.

Comment: i don't think there is a way but the manual method you mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to reset them all back to their defaults (as if the program was just opened) without doing it manually.

You will have to do it manually, but you can make it easier on yourself by organizing your code a bit.

For instance you can put your JTextComponents in an `ArrayList<JTextComponent>` and all other components of similar type into their own List as well. Then in your `resetAll()` method that you will write, iterate through all these lists resetting all components.

i.e.,

```
public void reset() {
  // for all JTextFields and JTextAreas
  for (JTextComponent textComponent: textComponentList) {
    textComponent.setText(""); 
  }

  // for all JCheckBoxes and JRadioButtons
  for (JToggleButton toggleButton: toggleButtonList) {
    toggleButton.setSelected(false);
  }

  // iterate through other lists doing likewise
}
```

Another way, which I don't recommend is to recursively go through all the components of your GUI, getting the type via instanceof and then setting the components based on type.